# GETDATE() do not match on my system time

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

My system returns all the data yesterday, but what it should do is that it should return all the data from today, my code works during on local database, but when I uploaded it on the web and started using online database the problem occurs

Here is my sql code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DisplayReservationToday]
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        r1.RESERVATION_ID, r4.LAST_NAME + ', ' + r4.FIRST_NAME AS NAME, 
        r2.ROOM_ID, r3.ROOM_TYPE, r2.NO_GUEST, 
        CONVERT(DATE, r2.ARRIVAL_DATE) AS ADate, 
        CONVERT(DATE, r2.DEPARTURE_DATE) AS DDate, r2.STATUS
    FROM 
        TBL_Transaction AS r1, TBL_SubTransaction AS r2, 
        TBL_Room AS r3, TBL_Client AS r4
    WHERE 
        r1.RESERVATION_ID = r2.RESERVATION_ID 
        AND r2.ROOM_ID = r3.ROOM_ID
        AND r1.USERNAME = r4.USERNAME
        AND UPPER(r2.STATUS) != UPPER('Cancelled')
        AND CONVERT(DATE, r2.ARRIVAL_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

Comment: May be your Online server is having different time zone

Comment: So my code is ok? and the only thing I should do is to contact my online server?

Comment: like @Prdp said, the difference in timezone between your database server is located and your own location. one way to neutralize timezone differences would be to use `UTC` as a standard to storing and retrieving data and use `GETUTCDATE()` instead of `GETDATE()`. you could always reset the timezone on your database server as well as a alternate solution

Comment: Well, what **datatype** are these columns `ARRIVAL_DATE` or `DEPARTURE_DATE` in your database? Seeing those are **dates** - they **should be** something like `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` already.....

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: thanks a lot! @ughai

Comment: Lots of product specific SQL there, which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening may be because the online database server is in different timezone than your local machine.

`GETDATE()` returns the local datetime value of the time zone in which your database dserver is present so you need to fetch date accordinng to the timezone to which your local machine belongs.

Eg. to convert to IST (Indian standard time) use offset of +5.30

```
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30') as [CurrentDateTime]
```

so in your query you can do the change

```
.
.
AND CONVERT(DATE, r2.ARRIVAL_DATE) = CONVERT(DATE, SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30'))
```

[**SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677334.aspx)